# Are new SPL tokens typically transferred from a Mint's token account to a user's Associated Token Account?

Tags: spl-token, associated-token-account, mint

I'm trying to mentally put together the relationship between the [various types of accounts involved in SPL tokens according to the Solana Cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#how-to-create-a-new-token): The cookbook says:

> This mint account is later used to mint tokens to a token account and create the initial supply.

Additionally [Solana Token Creator](https://github.com/jacobcreech/Token-Creator) docs say:

> Creating a Solana token requires the following steps:
>
> - Creating a new Mint account
> - Creating an associated token account
> - Minting an amount of the token to the associated token account
> - Adding the token metadata to the mint account

My understanding is that this means:

- [Every Token mint](https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#how-to-create-a-token-account) has:

  - Mint account - used to mint tokens (but does not store tokens)
  - Token Account - where new tokens are created. Associated Token Accounts are the most common way of making token accounts.
- Every user account has

  - A native Sol balance
  - 0 or more Associated token accounts (at lease one for every token type that belongs to this user account)

The documentation [mentions that transferChecked() moves tokens between two token accounts, but doesn't state what those accounts would typically be](https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#how-to-transfer-tokens).

I have guessed the following: after I have created tokens into the **mint's token account**, token are sent to users **from the mint's token account (which may be an ATA) to the user's Token Account (which may also be an ATA)**.

Is this correct? Or are tokens minted directly to user's token accounts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your main question: no, that's not per se typical. Technically, you *could* create an ATA for a Mint account, but that comes with some considerations.

##### How SPL Tokens Work

Put simply, a Mint represents a token, and an associated token account is just a counter that stores a user's balance of that token.

You can think of it like a double-pointer with a counter (balance) value:

```
Associated token account:
     --- What mint (token) does this correspond?
     --- What wallet does this correspond to?
     --- Balance
```

Every token Mint *is* a Mint account - It stores basic data related to an SPL token mint. A Mint is an entity in and of itself.

```
Mint: The new token M
```

When you create a new Mint its supply is 0.
In the cookbook page you linked, that's done at the top with `createMint()`; the only number provided is `decimals`.

Associated token accounts (ATAs) store which mint account and which user account they are associated with, and simply keep a balance.
In your cookbook link, that's done with `createAssociatedTokenAccount()` using the public keys of Alice and the Mint.

```
ATA: Person P has X balance of mint M
```

It can get confusing when you "mint to" someone's ATA, but all "mint to" really means is:

```
Mint To: increment the balance of the ATA for person P of mint M by X
```

In the cookbook example you linked, notice the only associated token account we introduce (before the transfer example) is Alice's ATA. We then mint to her ATA using `mintChecked()`.

Lastly, a transfer is similar to "mint to":

```
Transfer: Decrease Alice's ATA balance and increase Bob's ATA balance for mint M by X
```

**Token supply** is basically every ATA's balance of that token mint.

##### Using the Mint to Create an ATA

If you simply create an ATA for the Mint itself, like described above, it would look like this:

```
ATA: Person P has X balance of mint M   where P = M
```

Then you could use "mint to" just like above to mint tokens to that ATA.

However, the biggest thing to consider is: who owns the Mint account?

- If the Mint is a generated keypair, for example, you'd have to keep that private key handy if you ever wanted to sign off on a transfer out of the Mint's ATA.
- If your program owns the Mint, then your program can sign off on those transfers instead; but then anyone can conduct a transfer without certain safeguards in place.

This might be useful if you wanted to keep a certain supply of a token mint locked up in a "vault" so to speak. However, the typical practice is to create a new Mint and use a **Mint Authority** to dictate who can mint new tokens and when.

---

Hope that clears things up a bit.